# FB Login "Cancelled" when using the Unity FB SDK

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to use the FB SDK for Unity to login with FB but each time I try to click on the button from the example, the request is cancelled. Here are the steps I followed :

- Download the SDK with the example (properly configured with the app ID) which I launched
- Setup my app on facebook's developers website with the right package name, class name and key hash
- Launch the project, click on the FB.init button first and then on the Login button (I have a connected account on the device)

The result is that a new window is launched and closed instantly with status "Cancelled" showing on top of the phone's screen. If I go into the logs, I have the following message:

```
Facebook.Unity.LoginResult
LoginResult:
Error: null
RawResult: {"cancelled":true,"callback_id":"8","key_hash":"blabla"}
Cancelled: True
LoginResult: AccessToken: null
```

I checked that the key_hash was the same in my app's settings on the developer website and on this callback.